# How to count every x number backwards from y to zero?

Tags: python

I need help in python about making a code that will first ask a number for a starting number and then ask a number in which it will count spaces with that number until 0.

For example: input -10 and then input 2 and it will count from -10 to 0(0 not included) with 2 spaces: -10 -8 -6 -4 -2

My Attempt

```
a= int(input("""sisesta algusarv: """))
b= int(input("""sisesta arvu vahe: """))
list(range(a, 0, b))
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Start at reading about `range`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Comment: You should post what you tried to do, and not not just that you want code to be done for you.

Comment: hello, thanks for the feedback. I'll try to do something and post it here as the lines i made. I'll get back to you guys in about 30 minutes and after that any help will be definetly needed. :)

Comment: @RichardVillmann> at that point, your question is dead and will be closed (maybe you can even delete it yourself, I don't know the required rep). When you have done your homework, open a new question, with the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) recommendations in mind.

Comment: a= int(input("""sisesta algusarv: """))
b= int(input("""sisesta arvu vahe: """))
list(range(a, 0, b))
a is for the number you start with(in estonian)
b is for the space between the numbers ie: if 3 then 9 6 3 etc.
this should be the basis right? How can i improve this?

Comment: @RichardVillmann I would recommend opening up a new question, with your attempts or add your attempt as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your problem, I hope this helps!

```
def count_for_me(start=None, step=None):
    if not start:
        start = int(input('Start number?: '))
    if not step:
        step = int(input('Steps between each iteration?: '))
    return tuple(abs(x) if start > 0 else x for x in range(start if start < 0 else -start, 0, step))

print count_for_me()

print len(count_for_me())
```

Will return a list of each value.
I did not include any error checking to make sure the user typed in a correct value; no floats, only positive int for step etc...

Comment: Thank you a lot!! Just what i needed. Tested it out and it worked :) (y)